# Google Sheets. How to combine a checkbox and conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Here's my problem.

I have a cell with a checkbox. I can make it turn green when I check it. But I want it to turn green if no conditions are met and turn orange when a condition is met. The condition is that a range of four cells is empty (`<>""`). If all of them are empty - then checkbox becomes orange when pressed, if there is anything in any of the four cell then checkbox becomes green when pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom formula based on `countblank`

- Green = `=countblank(A3:D3) = 4`
- Orange = `=countblank(A3:D3) <>4`

---

**Rules**

[image: Custom Rules]

---

**Outcome: Green/all blank**

[image: All Blanks]

---

**Outcome: Orange/at least one cell not blank**

[image: One not blank]